# Serialize class which extends from HashMap Java

Tags: serialization, hashmap

I don't know why an HashMap instance is serializable and an instance of a class which extends HashMap isn't serializable.

So, this code works:

```
    HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
    ...
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    objOut.writeObject(map);
    objOut.close();
```

And this doesn't work:

```
    public class MyMap extends HashMap<String,String>{}
    ...
    MyMap  map=new MyMap();
    ...
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    objOut.writeObject(map);
    objOut.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was because an innerclass is serializable if has static modifier.